# What is an accurate translation of 自立自强?

Tags: meaning

I encountered the sentence 儿子说，他下定决心要**自立自强** in the [HSK6 Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/chinese-for-hsk-6); [week 4](https://www.coursera.org/learn/chinese-for-hsk-6/home/week/4) 第16课.  However, CC-CEDICT's entry for [自立自强](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E8%87%AA%E7%AB%8B%E8%87%AA%E5%BC%BA) is:

> 自立自強 自立自强 [zi4 li4 zi4 qiang2] /to strive for self-improvement/

But some example sentences ([YouDao](http://youdao.com/example/%E8%87%AA%E7%AB%8B%E8%87%AA%E5%BC%BA); [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%87%AA%E7%AB%8B%E8%87%AA%E5%BC%BA)) translate it to "self-reliance", which gives me the impression that CC-CEDICT's definition is inaccurate.  E.g.:

> 在家庭中，孩子从小就被灌输自立自强的观念。
> In the household, young kids are imbued with concept of self-reliance.

**Question**: What is an accurate translation of 自立自强?

I expect its precise meaning is simply the sum of its parts: "self-reliance 自立 and self-improvement 自强", but maybe there's more to this (e.g., multiple meanings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: What is an accurate translation of 自立自强?
> I expect its precise meaning is simply the sum of its parts

Yes, it is simply the sum of its parts

自立 - hold oneself up = self-reliance

自强 - strengthen oneself = self-strengthen

If you are independent, you wouldn't need to beg for other's help

If you are strong, you wouldn't be afraid of other's hinder or assault

*It fit perfectly into China's nationalistic ideal*

> 自立自強 自立自强 [zi4 li4 zi4 qiang2] /to strive for self-improvement

To make oneself more self-reliant and stronger is to improve oneself